# How to print new data on the same line?

Tags: bash

When I use `sudo apt-get install <package-name>` for installing any package, I observe the following:

```
Downloading some packages (78%)
```

This line once printed **never changes its position** but instead keeps on updating itself with percentage values. While other things are **changing** this line remains **constant**! How do they do it?

[image]

Comment: may be it has something to do with VDU memory.. direct read, write, save, restore, etc.

Comment: @null-pointer no need to trace your username in the screenshot when it's still on top of the window (`username@hostname:~`)... 8-) (Maybe you want to re-upload an edited version of your screenshot.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably need to look at what `echo -ne '\r'` does.

Here is an example:

```
echo -ne 'Downloading 1%\r'
sleep 1

echo -ne 'Downloading 100%\r'
sleep 1

echo -ne '\n'
```

Comment: Great! It has exactly same working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: nice one for scripts... +1

Comment: \r is also known as "carriage return", for the record :)

Comment: Ya! I tried it in a C program and it worked!

Comment: You can also use `\b` to back up 1 character: `echo -n "downloading: 001"; sleep 1; echo -e '\b\b\b100'`

Comment: @Nullpointer, for faster operations a direct access to VDU memory are more preferable for than using the string manipulation function.. as you'll have to write to comparatively lesser number of VDU memory addresses (the ones you want to update) while leaving the contents of the remaining addresses unchanged.. (in TurboC, but can't say about gcc)

Comment: @hash: Can you please explain how to do that since the OP *may not* be very familiar with VDU operations.

Comment: well in TurboC, you could check for the display adapter type so you can have the base address initialised, and for write operations you'd just assign the values to the address pointers...

Comment: @hash: Turbo C? Why would anyone use that on any linux-based distro? Would be great to have an explanation for gcc based compilers and SDK's.

Comment: I didn't suggest using TC.. just sharing what could be done there, haven't tried the similar in gcc.. I think there should be a way or even better.. but I'm not much aware about that..

Comment: Better to use printf rather than using options with echo.

Answer (score 0):

What Jobin said is correct, they do it with carriage return "\r". However, I think the OP was looking for a real world programming example.

Now, I'm not 100% familiar with the C/C++ syntax, but here's a working Python example:

Open a Terminal and type "python" to begin scripting.

Type the following code line for line, once you've type the last line hit the ENTER key twice and watch it work. Make sure after the "for i in range(11):" part, on the next lines you MUST hit the TAB key to indent in. It's proper Python formatting. If you don't hit TAB then you'll get an error.

```
import sys
import time
for i in range(11):
    time.sleep(1)
    i=i*10
    sys.stdout.write("\rDownload is %d%% complete!" %i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

So that's KIND OF how the terminal does what you asked about.

Comment: Thanks dude! I already tried this in C and it works, I have also mentioned this in the comments!